# Is it possible to put all environment variables in a file and upload it to heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables, digital-ocean

I know you can set environment variables in dashboard. However I want a solution that is less platform oriented, say I want to move to digital ocean or something. Is there a way I can put all secrets/(development|production) etc into one file and then tell heroku or whatever platform I'm using to read from it.

Of course I won't be adding this file into git, but instead put it into .gitignore along node_modules/ .

I remember seeing something about yml file.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can achieve something like this.

Using the [heroku platform api](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-vars), you can programmatically retrieve and set config vars.
That would allow you to run any script you wish to set the config vars on your app.

Using the unofficial [heroku-config](https://github.com/xavdid/heroku-config) CLI plugin, you can get `heroku config:pull` and `heroku config:pull` locally, allowing you to pull and push config vars from and to an app.

Finally, you mention a yaml file. You're probably thinking of [app.json](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema). That file is used for the Heroku Button and Review Apps features, and you can indeed set config vars within it.
It will only be executed when the app is created (as a button deploy, or a review app) though, not with every deploy.